# Label/Text inside NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

It seems that everybody that needs some text for a `NSProgressIndicator` (i.e. showing the percentage of a download) ends up putting the text above the widget, or next to it.

Cannot you really show any text inside the `NSProgressIndicator` widget?

An example of what I mean:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

In IB, just embed your progress indicator in a custom view, add a label to that view, and center both the progress indicator and the label within the custom view.

Comment: The same way you do for any views.  Create a custom view, a label and the progress bar using alloc initWithFrame and then add the label and the progress bar as subviews to the custom view.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a label where ever you want. The progress indicator doesn't have a text property. So yes, you could put a label onto a progress indicator. If that would look good is an other question.

Comment: how to do it? for example, if I want the text to be in the center of the widget?